# How to test componentDidMount with has document.getElementByClassName in react using jest and enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I am trying to test functionality using react 16 with jest and enzyme, I have written the test case please have a look at the code below which I have writtes and also I I am trying to test. Any suggetion would be great help.

**What I want to test?**

```
  componentDidMount() {
if (this.props.isSubmissionComplete) {
  window.location.href = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH;
}

if (document.getElementsByClassName("continue-button")[0]) {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("continue-button")[0]
    .classList.add("hidden");
}
if (document.getElementsByClassName("back-button")[0]) {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("back-button")[0]
    .classList.remove("offset-sm-1");
}

//Sets the applicable coverages to the state for use in the post submission pages
var coverageList = this.renderCoverageList();
this.props.updateApplicableCoverages(coverageList);
  }
```

**The code I have written to test.**

```
let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <FraudStatement/>
    );
  });

 it("should hide the continue button if it exists", () => {

expect(wrapper.find(".continue-button").hasClass("hidden")).toBe(true);
  });
```

**The ERROR I get.**

```
   Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: false Jest
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Basically here I have tried to create a new element in DOM with s shallow rendering the component, and then testing the if condition, if the condition satisfies it will expect the assertation statement.

The code also marks 100% code coverage when you test.

```
const continueButton = document.createElement("button");
continueButton.classList.add("continue-button");
document.body.appendChild(continueButton);

const wrapper = shallow(<FraudStatement />);
const buttonWrapper = wrapper.find(".continue-button");
if (!buttonWrapper.exists()) {
  return;
}
const isHidden = buttonWrapper.hasClass("hidden");
expect(isHidden).toBe(true);
document.body.removeChild(continueButton);
```